# Why is this for loop so demanding?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, for-loop, kivy

```
def number_add(self, *args):#not tested yet

    if len(self.player1dict) == len(self.imported_ideas) and len(self.player2dict) == len(self.imported_ideas):
        self.debug.text = 'Your Results:'
        self.scrollview.clear_widgets()
        self.scrollview.add_widget(self.answer_label)

        for i in self.imported_ideas:
            self.totalsdict[i] = self.player1dict[i] + self.player2dict[i]
        for i in self.totalsdict:
            if self.totalsdict[i] == 20:
                self.array_ans.append('You scored 20/20 for: ' + i)
            elif self.totalsdict[i] >14:
                self.array_ans.append('You scored very highly for: ' + i)
            elif self.player1dict[i] > 5 and self.player2dict[i] >5 or self.totalsdict[i] >= 13:
                self.array_ans.append('You scored highly for: ' + i) 
            else:
                pass

        '''for i in self.player1dict:
            if (self.player1dict[i] + self.player2dict[i])== 20:
                self.array_ans.append('You scored 20/20 for: ' + i)
            elif (self.player1dict[i] + self.player2dict[i]) >14:
                self.array_ans.append('You scored very highly for: ' + i)
            elif self.player1dict[i] > 5 and self.player2dict[i] >5 or (self.player1dict[i] + self.player2dict[i]) >= 13:
                self.array_ans.append('You scored highly for: ' + i) 
            else:
                pass'''


    else:
        self.debug.text = 'error, dictionary lengths not right'

    self.answer_label.text = "\n".join(self.array_ans) #a better method for presenting ideas
    self.answer_label.height=(self.r+10)*self.answer_label.font_size
```

Currently the two dictionaries are about 35 key:value pairs long

I have been using this function to add together scores given by two players and print out results. However it takes several seconds to compute on my laptop and a matter of minutes on an android phone. Why is this so demanding?

the commented out method is just as slow

is there some great inefficiency in the code?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT I ran the method through cProfiler

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:478(_set_text)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 clock.py:243(__call__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 dampedscroll.py:93(on_value)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 label.py:163(_trigger_texture_update)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 lang.py:1324(delayed_call_fn)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 main.py:201(number_add)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:212(_get_vbar)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:239(_get_hbar)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:380(_set_viewport_size)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:383(on__viewport)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:446(_update_effect_widget)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:452(_update_effect_x_bounds)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:459(_update_effect_y_bounds)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:466(_update_effect_bounds)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:485(_update_effect_y)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:766(add_widget)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 scrollview.py:777(remove_widget)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 widget.py:204(__eq__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 widget.py:212(__self__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 widget.py:316(add_widget)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 widget.py:373(remove_widget)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 widget.py:392(clear_widgets)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 widget.py:539(get_top)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 widget.py:552(get_center_x)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 widget.py:564(get_center_y)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas' objects}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'bind' of 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas' objects}
```

Comment: Have you [profiled](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Are the dictionaries being changed when this function is called? Do you know if the issue is related with the app logic or with the widgets?